# Newest GLSL Spec with Least Changes?

Tags: glsl

What's the newest OpenGL GLSL specification that provides as little change to the language such that learning it won't be redundant when moving to a newer version that's also available now, for the future. As such I want to be able to make my shaders work on as much hardware as possible without learning a completely deprecated language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you define "redundant".

If you're purely talking about the core/compatibility feature removal, that only ever happened *once*, in the transition from OpenGL 3.0 to 3.1 (in GLSL version terms, 1.30 to 1.40).

Every shader version from 1.40 onward will be supported by any OpenGL implementation. Every shading language version from 1.10 onward will be supported by any compatibility profile implementation.

If by "redundant", you mean that you don't want to have to learn new grammar to access language changes that don't affect new hardware ([separate programs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Separate_programs), [explicit attribute](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) and [uniform](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Explicit_uniform_location) specifications, etc, all of which have zero hardware dependencies), tough. Pick your version based on whatever minimum hardware you want to support and stick with it.

Comment: Yah I believe that's when the fixed pipeline was removed and things like gl_Color, gl_Perspective (not sure if those are correct) were removed from glsl. I also believe the way information was transferred from vertex to fragment shader has changed (no more varying keyword?). What I mean by redundant is, if in version 1.40 there was a way to do X but then in version 3.30 (I believe the standardized glsl verioning for GL 3.3+?) they introduced a new method to do the same thing I would rather learn 3.30.

Comment: @skln: The ARB will *always* be introducing new methods to do stuff. Every GLSL version is going to have new stuff that won't necessarily be tied to any hardware. From 3.30's explicit attribute location to 4.40's [huge](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback#In-shader_specification) bevvy [of features](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Interface_components). The future will always have new stuff. What you code to should be based on what hardware you have and want to serve.

Comment: @skin it's not just the removal of the fixed pipeline, it's also the addition of new programmable stages — e.g. `varying` was specifically tied to the notion that there would be a vertex shader and a fragment shader and that completes the list of shaders. So it meant 'this is an output' in one place and 'this is an input' in another. `in` and `out` replaced it. Anyway, just stick to the GLSLs that go with GL 3+ and you'll be fine for now.